# Spring,Struts,Hibernate application throws an excpetion org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException

Tags: spring, hibernate, struts

While I developing struts1,Spring,Hibernate application I got an Exception

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
Error creating bean with name
'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource
[/WEB-INF/spring-servlet.xml]: 
Invocation of init method failed; nested exception
is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:     
net.sf.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.setInterceptDuringConstruction(Z)V

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name   'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring-servlet.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: net.sf.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.setInterceptDuringConstruction(Z)V
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1420)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:288)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:190)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:563)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:895)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:425)
at org.springframework.web.struts.ContextLoaderPlugIn.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoaderPlugIn.java:356)
at org.springframework.web.struts.ContextLoaderPlugIn.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoaderPlugIn.java:297)
at org.springframework.web.struts.ContextLoaderPlugIn.init(ContextLoaderPlugIn.java:227)
at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.initModulePlugIns(ActionServlet.java:1158)
at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.init(ActionServlet.java:473)
at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:212)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1161)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:981)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4042)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4348)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:791)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:771)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:525)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:920)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectories(HostConfig.java:883)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:492)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1138)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:311)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:117)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1053)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:719)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1045)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:443)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:516)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:710)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:566)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:288)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:413)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: net.sf.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.setInterceptDuringConstruction(Z)V
at org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.cglib.CGLIBLazyInitializer.getProxyFactory(CGLIBLazyInitializer.java:126)
at org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.cglib.CGLIBProxyFactory.postInstantiate(CGLIBProxyFactory.java:43)
at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.PojoEntityTuplizer.buildProxyFactory(PojoEntityTuplizer.java:162)
at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.AbstractEntityTuplizer.<init>(AbstractEntityTuplizer.java:135)
at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.PojoEntityTuplizer.<init>(PojoEntityTuplizer.java:55)
at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.EntityEntityModeToTuplizerMapping.<init>(EntityEntityModeToTuplizerMapping.java:56)
at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.EntityMetamodel.<init>(EntityMetamodel.java:302)
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.<init>(AbstractEntityPersister.java:434)
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.SingleTableEntityPersister.<init>(SingleTableEntityPersister.java:109)
at org.hibernate.persister.PersisterFactory.createClassPersister(PersisterFactory.java:55)
at org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:226)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1300)
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean.newSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:860)
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:779)
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.AbstractSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractSessionFactoryBean.java:211)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1477)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1417)
... 41 more
Mar 23, 2013 12:02:25 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Marking servlet action as unavailable
Mar 23, 2013 12:02:25 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext loadOnStartup
SEVERE: Servlet /Bank threw load() exception
javax.servlet.UnavailableException
at     org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.initModulePlugIns(ActionServlet.java:1169)
at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.init(ActionServlet.java:473)
at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:212)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1161)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:981)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4042)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4348)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:791)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:771)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:525)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:920)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectories(HostConfig.java:883)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:492)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1138)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:311)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:117)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1053)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:719)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1045)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:443)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:516)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:710)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:566)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at     sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:288)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:413)
```

how I can resolve it I try many solution like I used hibernate-3.2.6.ga jar and cglib-nodep-2.1_3jar but still this problem is not resolved.Please help me i just stuck here.

This is my spring-servlet.xml file

```
<beans 
xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans          http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">
 <context:annotation-config/>   
  <bean id="dataSource"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost/vik" />
    <property name="username" value="root" />
   </bean>

<bean id="sessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource">
        <ref bean="dataSource" />
    </property>
        <property name="mappingResources">
        <list>
            <value>
                com/hibernate/Customer.hbm.xml</value>
            <value>com/hibernate/Account.hbm.xml</value>
        </list>
    </property>

    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="htemp" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate"
    autowire="constructor" />
<bean id="txManager"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager"
    autowire="byName" />    
<beans>
```

Comment: Can you show us the "sessionfactory" bean configuration in applicationcontext.xml?

Answer (score 0):

About your question, here is my solution:

```
just use cglib-2.1_3jboss.jar instead of cglib-nodep-2.1_3jar.
```

It will work well, Good luck :)